# Javascript webgl2 - Mac OS X - texsubimage3D not working properly when repaint the canva

Tags: javascript, webgl2

I made a working function on windows os that update a 3D-texture (slide by slide) with async loading function.
At the end of each async call, I put a repaint function that work properly under windows but on Mac Os after a correct first update, all the texture updates seem to be made at index offset 0.
If I suppress the repaint function, the texture is correctly updated.

Do you think the problem can be solved? (what about the possibility of mutex?)
Thank you for your response and your time

```
     async function gpuload(image){
        ctx.bindTexture(ctx.TEXTURE_3D, ctx.TEXTURE0);
ctx.texSubImage3D(ctx.TEXTURE_3D,0,1,1,indexZ,Columns,Rows,1,ctx.LUMINANCE, ctx.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image));
        repaint();
            }
```

Comment: whats the active texture unit and which texture is bound when you call that function? it's not normal to have an async function without binding a texture inside the function.

Comment: i didn't write all the function ctx.bindTexture(ctx.TEXTURE_3D, ctx.TEXTURE0);

Comment: which browser??

Comment: firefox and chrome : same behavior

Comment: Your bind statement is invalid. Also are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: No error at all, the subtexture indexZ zero are replaced one by one after each iteration

Comment: ok well I don't know how to help without more code. The fact that you're uploading to x,y = 1,1 instead of 0,0 is suspicious. Are all your image slices the same size? Do they match the size of the texture - 1? I'm not near a mac ATM. Does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/jec8r6u7/) work